Parsing data in an HTML table pulled from a website using R
I'm trying to parse HTML tables and so far I've successfully managed to convert the HTML tables into a single data frame but I need to modify the code to parse the text in one of the columns to spread over two columns.
So, if you look at the HTML code below the information I need to split is separated by a <br> tag. For instance, take one of the cells in the first row  <td class="nowrap">LMS - City 1, 2, 3 YSA<br><small>612 Glen Rd</small></td>, when entered into a dataframe it will read "LMS - City 1, 2, 3 YSA612 Glen Rd" under the Location column. But what I need is to split this information over two columns, one for the Location name "LMS - City 1, 2, 3 YSA" and another for the address "612 Glen Rd."
Some of the information below has been changed to protect sensitive information.
CODE:
######### Import Library #########
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(writexl)
library(rvest)
library(httr)


######### Pull data from Website ########### 
start.time <- Sys.time()

# Enter login URL
login_url <- "URL"

# Create a session
session <- html_session(login_url)

# Extract the form from the login page
form <- html_form(session)[[1]]

# Fill in the login credentials
filled_form <- set_values(form, 
                          username = "name",
                          password = "pass")

# Submit the form
submit_form(session, filled_form)

# Initialize an empty list to store table data
all_tables <- list()

# Loop over each page
for (i in 1:6) {
  # Construct the URL for each page
  page_url <- paste0("URL.asp?pgNum=", i, "&sortBy=&sortOrder=ASC")

  # Jump to page
  page <- session %>% 
    jump_to(page_url)
  
  # Parse the HTML content of the page
  parsed_page <- page %>% read_html()
  
  # Extract table data
  table <- parsed_page %>%
    html_nodes("table") %>%
    html_table(fill = TRUE)
  
  # Append table data to the list
  all_tables <- c(all_tables, table)
}

# Combine all tables into one data frame
combined_table <- do.call(rbind, all_tables)

# Write combined table to Excel file
write.xlsx(combined_table, "excel_file.xlsx", row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE)

end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- round(end.time - start.time, 2)
time.taken

HTML CODE:
<table id="reportTable" class="table table-hover table-responsive" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="page-break-before:always !important;">

    <tbody><tr>
<th class="  first"><a class="hidden-print" href="URL.asp?sortBy=TIMEID&amp;sortOrder=ASC&amp;pgSize=10000&amp;pgNum=1">ID</a><span class="visible-print">ID</span></th>
<th class="  "><a class="hidden-print" href="URL.asp?sortBy=UserName&amp;sortOrder=ASC&amp;pgSize=10000&amp;pgNum=1">Name</a><span class="visible-print">Name</span></th>
<th class="  "><a class="hidden-print" href="URL.asp?sortBy=LocationName&amp;sortOrder=ASC&amp;pgSize=10000&amp;pgNum=1">Location</a><span class="visible-print">Location</span></th>
<th class="  "><a class="hidden-print" href="URL.asp?sortBy=TaskName&amp;sortOrder=ASC&amp;pgSize=10000&amp;pgNum=1">Tasks</a><span class="visible-print">Tasks</span></th>
<th class="  ">Field Notes</th><th class="  "><a class="hidden-print" href="URL.asp?sortBy=StartTime&amp;sortOrder=ASC&amp;pgSize=10000&amp;pgNum=1">Start</a><span class="visible-print">Start</span></th>
<th class="  "><a class="hidden-print" href="URL.asp?sortBy=Completedtime&amp;sortOrder=ASC&amp;pgSize=10000&amp;pgNum=1">Finish</a><span class="visible-print">Finish</span></th>
<th class="  ">Min</th><th class="  last"><a class="hidden-print" href="URL.asp?sortBy=CostEstimate&amp;sortOrder=ASC&amp;pgSize=10000&amp;pgNum=1">Charge</a><span class="visible-print">Charge</span></th>
</tr>


    <tr>
      <td class="text-center"><small><a href="/timerecords.asp?action=Edit&amp;TIMEID=742900" target="_blank">742900</a></small></td>
      <td class="nowrap">Business1</td>
      <td class="nowrap">LMS - City 1, 2, 3 YSA<br><small>612 Glen Rd</small></td>
      <td class="nowrap">Door Repair</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="nowrap">7/9/2024 1:00 AM</td>
      <td class="nowrap"> 1:00 AM</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td class="text-right">195</td>
    </tr>
    
    
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center"><small><a href="/timerecords.asp?action=Edit&amp;TIMEID=742899" target="_blank">742899</a></small></td>
      <td class="nowrap">Business2</td>
      <td class="nowrap">LLL Station 123 - Emerson<br><small>1234 Legend Road</small></td>
      <td class="nowrap">Septic Pump</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="nowrap">7/4/2024 1:00 AM</td>
      <td class="nowrap"> 1:00 AM</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td class="text-right">956</td>
    </tr>
    
    
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center"><small><a href="/timerecords.asp?action=Edit&amp;TIMEID=742898" target="_blank">742898</a></small></td>
      <td class="nowrap">Business3</td>
      <td class="nowrap">Puro Everton<br><small>123 Okay Avenue East</small></td>
      <td class="nowrap">Weeding</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="nowrap">7/10/2024 1:00 AM</td>
      <td class="nowrap"> 1:00 AM</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td class="text-right">850</td>
    </tr>
    
    
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center"><small><a href="/timerecords.asp?action=Edit&amp;TIMEID=742897" target="_blank">742897</a></small></td>
      <td class="nowrap">Business4</td>
      <td class="nowrap">MJ Building<br><small>123 MJ Ave</small></td>
      <td class="nowrap">Parkade Sweep</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="nowrap">6/28/2024 1:00 AM</td>
      <td class="nowrap"> 1:00 AM</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td class="text-right">670</td>
    </tr>

Sorry if I did not upload some of the information correctly but hopefully this is enough to get an idea of what I'm trying to do.

One rather simple option is to process response content before parsing html and  replacing <br> with some placeholder. This way you can still use html_table() and don't need to write your own table parser. Column in resulting tibble can then separated by that placeholder.
Assuming that <br> can only occur in <td> elements of that specific column
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

# getting html content as text from rvest session might look something like this:
# page <- session_jump_to(session, page_url)
# content_text <- httr::content(page$response, as = "text")

# replace all "<br>" occurrences with something that would not get parsed by rvest, {-br-}
# parse table, separate column by placeholder
content_text |> 
  str_replace_all(fixed("<br>"), "{-br-}") |> 
  read_html() |> 
  html_element("table") |> 
  html_table() |> 
  separate_wider_delim(LocationLocation, delim = "{-br-}", names = c("Location", "Address"))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 10
#>     IDID NameName  Location          Address TasksTasks `Field Notes` StartStart
#>    <int> <chr>     <chr>             <chr>   <chr>      <lgl>         <chr>     
#> 1 742900 Business1 LMS - City 1, 2,… 612 Gl… Door Repa… NA            7/9/2024 …
#> 2 742899 Business2 LLL Station 123 … 1234 L… Septic Pu… NA            7/4/2024 …
#> 3 742898 Business3 Puro Everton      123 Ok… Weeding    NA            7/10/2024…
#> 4 742897 Business4 MJ Building       123 MJ… Parkade S… NA            6/28/2024…
#> # ℹ 3 more variables: FinishFinish <chr>, Min <int>, ChargeCharge <int>

Example content_text :
content_text <- 
  '<table id="reportTable" class="table table-hover table-responsive" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="page-break-before:always !important;">

    <tbody><tr>
<th class="  first"><a class="hidden-print" href="URL.asp?sortBy=TIMEID&amp;sortOrder=ASC&amp;pgSize=10000&amp;pgNum=1">ID</a><span class="visible-print">ID</span></th>
<th class="  "><a class="hidden-print" href="URL.asp?sortBy=UserName&amp;sortOrder=ASC&amp;pgSize=10000&amp;pgNum=1">Name</a><span class="visible-print">Name</span></th>
<th class="  "><a class="hidden-print" href="URL.asp?sortBy=LocationName&amp;sortOrder=ASC&amp;pgSize=10000&amp;pgNum=1">Location</a><span class="visible-print">Location</span></th>
<th class="  "><a class="hidden-print" href="URL.asp?sortBy=TaskName&amp;sortOrder=ASC&amp;pgSize=10000&amp;pgNum=1">Tasks</a><span class="visible-print">Tasks</span></th>
<th class="  ">Field Notes</th><th class="  "><a class="hidden-print" href="URL.asp?sortBy=StartTime&amp;sortOrder=ASC&amp;pgSize=10000&amp;pgNum=1">Start</a><span class="visible-print">Start</span></th>
<th class="  "><a class="hidden-print" href="URL.asp?sortBy=Completedtime&amp;sortOrder=ASC&amp;pgSize=10000&amp;pgNum=1">Finish</a><span class="visible-print">Finish</span></th>
<th class="  ">Min</th><th class="  last"><a class="hidden-print" href="URL.asp?sortBy=CostEstimate&amp;sortOrder=ASC&amp;pgSize=10000&amp;pgNum=1">Charge</a><span class="visible-print">Charge</span></th>
</tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="text-center"><small><a href="/timerecords.asp?action=Edit&amp;TIMEID=742900" target="_blank">742900</a></small></td>
      <td class="nowrap">Business1</td>
      <td class="nowrap">LMS - City 1, 2, 3 YSA<br><small>612 Glen Rd</small></td>
      <td class="nowrap">Door Repair</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="nowrap">7/9/2024 1:00 AM</td>
      <td class="nowrap"> 1:00 AM</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td class="text-right">195</td>
    </tr>
    
    
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center"><small><a href="/timerecords.asp?action=Edit&amp;TIMEID=742899" target="_blank">742899</a></small></td>
      <td class="nowrap">Business2</td>
      <td class="nowrap">LLL Station 123 - Emerson<br><small>1234 Legend Road</small></td>
      <td class="nowrap">Septic Pump</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="nowrap">7/4/2024 1:00 AM</td>
      <td class="nowrap"> 1:00 AM</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td class="text-right">956</td>
    </tr>
    
    
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center"><small><a href="/timerecords.asp?action=Edit&amp;TIMEID=742898" target="_blank">742898</a></small></td>
      <td class="nowrap">Business3</td>
      <td class="nowrap">Puro Everton<br><small>123 Okay Avenue East</small></td>
      <td class="nowrap">Weeding</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="nowrap">7/10/2024 1:00 AM</td>
      <td class="nowrap"> 1:00 AM</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td class="text-right">850</td>
    </tr>
    
    
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center"><small><a href="/timerecords.asp?action=Edit&amp;TIMEID=742897" target="_blank">742897</a></small></td>
      <td class="nowrap">Business4</td>
      <td class="nowrap">MJ Building<br><small>123 MJ Ave</small></td>
      <td class="nowrap">Parkade Sweep</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="nowrap">6/28/2024 1:00 AM</td>
      <td class="nowrap"> 1:00 AM</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td class="text-right">670</td>
    </tr>
'


As a side note, what you have in that loop is basically a textbook case of Circle 2 of R Inferno - Growing Objects. It's kind of fine if for-loops feel more natural than lapply / map & co, but you can still allocate space for that whole list and avoid combining in a loop:
all_tables <- vector(mode = "list", length = 6)
for (i in 1:6){
  ...
  all_tables[[i]] <- table_
}


Great answer, thank you!
Coming from Java for-loops definitely feel more natural to me. Still familiarizing myself with what R can do
